# Best way to write a 3d int Array to file (and update it)?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, writetofile

I'm trying to save a 3d array to file in a format that can be easily retrieved and updated. I'm not having much luck in finding a simple way to do it.

it's an int array with 3 dimensions. I'd prefer a save method that resembles something like this:

```
//save
for (int z1 = 0; z1 <= z; z1++)
{
  for (int c = 0; c < m.Length; c++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
      writeToFile("matrix.txt", matrix[z1][c][x];
    }
  }
}
```

and a similar retrieval method, but at this point I'm not at all picky, anything that will save to file and be easily retrieved is fine.

the above is only preferred as it would allow me to save just the portion of the array that hold data.

the size of the array is something like m[4000][7000][4] but it's sparsely populated.

EDIT: After making longer runs it turns out my machine is not capable of running an array of this size so I will be switching to an xml data set instead. Thank you all for your suggestions, sorry I can't better implement them.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: file format does metter? Perhaps, you might want to serialize an object with your 3d array into xml file.

Comment: @Dmitry no, file format does not matter. Do you have method for writing and retrieving data to xml? thanks

Comment: Why do not use serialize your object (3D array)?

Comment: Create a class with your 3d int. class My3dInt { pubic int[10][10][10] ;}. Mark the class as [Serializable] Save your array into this field and use Xml Serialization. See examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/vstudio/58a18dwa(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

What you need - is tools.

Now these are my recommendations there are other solutions, maybe even better suited...

First of all go [here](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/docs/) and familiarize yourself with this library. what you need is probably [this sparse matrix data structure](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single/SparseMatrix.htm) or maybe a [Sparse vector](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single/SparseVector.htm).

Second,if you don't care about the format in which the file is saved, then .Net has a wonderful thing called binary serialization [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

now this all sounds pretty complicated but its pretty much along the lines of:
    //this is was writen without VS...

```
// create a matrix, Im using a dense one, but you can use a sparse matrix in pretty much the same way
Matrix<double> matrix = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] {
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,2,3,4},
        {4,3,2,1}});

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

// saving
using(var fileStream1 = File.Create("file.file"))
{
    formatter.Serialize(fileStream1, matrix);
}

Matrix<double> newMatrix= null;

// retreving    
using(var fileStream2 = File.Open("file.file"))
{
    newMatrix = (Matrix<double>)formatter.DeSerialize(fileStream2);
}
```

performance wise this should be pretty efficient for sparse matrixes (the example shows a dense matrix) because Math.Net uses [CSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR_or_CRS.29) so save their data...

the links:
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/docs/
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single/SparseMatrix.htm
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single/SparseVector.htm
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR_or_CRS.29

Answer (score 1):

You could use something similar to graph theory, where you would save your graph as a list of adiacent nodes, but in your case extended to 3 dimensions : Only save the data which has a value different than 0.
On the other hand, you should use multiple arrays in the form of `int [,,] matrix=new int[4000,7000,4]` instead of separate indexing.
Your save method could look like this, considering the previous :

```
for (int z1 = 0; z1 <= z; z1++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < m.Length; c++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            if(matrix[z1,c,x]!=0)
            {
                File.AppendAllText("matrix.txt",z1+" "+c+" "+x+" "+matrix[z1,c,x]+System.Environment.NewLine)//NewLine to isolate each matrix value on a different line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, your Read method should look like so :

```
string[] lines=File.ReadAllLines("matrix.txt");
//assuming your matrix is initialized with 0s
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    string[] elementsInLine=line.Split(' ');
    int z1=int.Parse(elementsInLine[0]);
    int c=int.Parse(elementsInLine[1]);
    int x=int.Parse(elementsInLine[2]);
    matrix[z1,c,x]=int.Parse(elementsInLine[3]);
}
```

I've made some assumptions regarding the format of your output/input file, hopefully they are helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Newtonsoft.Json library to serialize your collection and then write it to a file.

http://james.newtonking.com/json

You can use StreamWriter / StreamReader for i/o operations on the file

Example: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 1):

Given that your Array is only sparsely populated writing out only the non-zero values seems to be the best way.

```
    const int DIM0 = 4000;
    const int DIM1 = 7000;
    const int DIM2 = 4;
    int[, ,] array = new int[DIM0 , DIM1 , DIM2 ];

    void writeArray(string fileName)
    {
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

        for (int k=0; k < DIM2 ; k++)
        for (int j=0; j < DIM1 ; j++)
        for (int i=0; i < DIM0 ; i++)
        {
            if (array[i,j,k] != 0)
                SB.Append(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}\r\n",i,j,k,array[i,j,k]) );
        }
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, SB.ToString().TrimEnd('\r').TrimEnd('\n')  );
    }

    void readArray(string fileName)
    {
        string s = File.ReadAllText(fileName).Replace("\r","");
        string[] p = s.Split('\n');
        bool error = false;
        foreach (string e in p)
        {
            string[] n = e.Split(',');
            int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int v = 0;
            error  = !Int32.TryParse(n[0], out i) ;
            error &= !Int32.TryParse(n[1], out j);
            error &= !Int32.TryParse(n[2], out k);
            error &= !Int32.TryParse(n[3], out v);
            if (!error) array[i, j, k] = v;
            else { /*abort with error message..*/}
        }
    }
```

Edit: I have exchanged the ';' for line breaks, just in case the array in not quite so thinnly filled, so that no line length limits can get hit..